# Как сделать проверку совпадения в строке независимо от регистра?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте.

Делаю проверку в строке "My Site": есть ли там, допустим, "Site". Но как сделать, чтобы можно и в строке "My site" проверять, чтобы строка не зависела от регистра?

```
if(preg_match('/(Site|my)/i',$list[$i]['name'])){
// найдено
}
```

Этот код не работает.
И какая разница с этим кодом:

```
if(preg_match('#(Site|my)#i',$list[$i]['name'])){
// найдено
}
```

Какая разница с '#' и '/'?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Например Вы хотите найти слово site:  

    /\bsite\b/i
site или my:  

    /\b(?:site|my)\b/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, по поводу разницы `#` и `/`. Никакой. Просто иногда, когда пишется регулярное выражение, в котором будет много слешей, то их приходится экранировать и в результате код превращается в кашу. Если же использовать "решетку", то слеши не нужно экранировать. Но можно к примеру использовать `|` - дело вкуса.

По поводу регулярного выражения. Оно то правильное, но только искать оно будет другое. Для выражения `Site|my` подходят такие строки Sitey и Sitmy.

Для решения Вашей задачи нужна такая регулярка `/site/i`. Если же нужно искать либо site, либо my, тогда где то так `/(site)|(my)/i`.

Comment: альтернатива захватывает максимально возможную группу. Выражение `(site|my)` верно

Comment: Вроде оно для кирилицы не работает. 
$s='Прометей / Prometheus (2012) HD 1080p | Трейлер';

if(preg_match('/трейлер/i',$s)){
echo'ok';
}
Просьба подсказать, уже все перепробовал.

Comment: Потому что кодировки разные. И работать не будет.
Правильный вариант - сохранять файлы в utf, апачу подсказать, что бы передавал всё в юникоде, и использовать модификатор u в регулярке (писать после i).
Если же текст с внешнего мира приходит не в той кодировке, что нужно, то тогда его нужно конвертировать таким способом `$new_text= iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $old_text);`